# Tensorflow 2.0 dataset and dataloader

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I am a pytorch user, and I am used to the data.dataset and data.dataloader api in pytorch. I am trying to build a same model with tensorflow 2.0, and I wonder whether there is an api that works similarly with these api in pytorch.

If there is no such api, can any of you tell me how people usually do to implement the data loading part in tensorflow ? I've used tensorflow 1, but never had an experience with dataset api. I've hard coded before. I hope there is something like overriding **getitem** with only index as an input.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: look up the `tf.data.*` API

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using the `tf.data` API, you will usually also make use of the `map` function.

In PyTorch, your `__getItem__` call basically fetches an element from your data structure given in `__init__` and transforms it if necessary.

In TF2.0, you do the same by initializing a `Dataset` using one of the `Dataset.from_...` functions (see `from_generator`, `from_tensor_slices`, `from_tensors`); this is essentially the `__init__` part of a PyTorch `Dataset`. Then, you can call `map` to do the element-wise manipulations you would have in `__getItem__`.

Tensorflow datasets are pretty much fancy iterators, so by design you don't access their elements using indices, but rather by traversing them.

The [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) on `tf.data` is very useful and provides a wide variety of examples.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks a lot Mat.

Comment: @piljae.chae Just curious, how did you find the `tf.data` API? I love the PyTorch `data` API but just hired onto a TensorFlow shop and am having to re-learn a few things. I honestly wonder if you couldn't mix and match here?

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with Pytorch but Tensorflow implements the Keras API which has the Sequence class that is:

> Base object for fitting to a sequence of data, such as a dataset

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

This class contains getitem for an index.